# Grid Based AI Pathfinding

Tags: ai, path-finding, game-maker

I'm creating a top-down RPG and I have the movement system set up for the player character - it is alike to Pokemon in the movement sense in that it looks smooth but it is aligned to a grid. Since I have the player sorted I was trying to figure out how to use this movement principle for the Enemy AI's Pathfinding but I haven't figured out how to do it; I was wondering if anyone has a possible solution to this.

Comment: Do a Google search for A-star pathfinding. The algorithm is really easy to understand if you read up on it.